# Should I pass the $form parameter when building system_settings_form?

Tags: 7, forms

Usually I refer to core for best practices. When I was building a system settings form I copied and repurposed the following core implementation.

This define the path for the system setting form that gets invoked via `drupal_get_form()`

```
  $items['admin/structure/menu/settings'] = array(
    'title' => 'Settings',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('menu_configure'),
    'access arguments' => array('administer menu'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 5,
    'file' => 'menu.admin.inc',
    );
```

And this is the function that build the form:

```
       /**
        * Menu callback; Build the form presenting menu configuration options.
        */
        function menu_configure() {
          // The form definition is here ..
          //.....

        return system_settings_form($form);
       }
```

So my question is why isn't the `$form` param passed to the form function `menu_configure()`?
There are other examples of system settings forms in core, called via the `drupal_get_from()` that do not have the `$form` parameter in the parameter list. So is it optional in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The form parameter is passed from `drupal_get_form()`, but if you choose to start a new form array it doesn't really matter. The form works as expected.

However, it's good practice I think to include `$form` and `$form_state` in the parameter list because if you ever change your menu entry to pass an argument, then all you need to do in your form builder callback is to add it to the list at the end.